# Duplicate row power BI with a condition

Tags: duplicates, powerbi

I have this table in Power BI (Col1 is the Departement and Col2 is a person, a person could work in 2 different departements) I'd like to split Col1 and duplicate the row.

```
Col1    Col2
A||B    James
A||C    Amy
```

what i'd like to have is this

```
col1   Col2
A       James
B       James
A       Amy
C       Amy
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to **Power Query Editor** and **Split** the column as shown below-

[image]

Here is the output-

[image]